# Uploading image location in PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, photo

I am trying to make a form in php that uploads an image from mobile. The name of the image is stored in mysql database for retrieval. The code is working fine. I wanted to know if I can store the location of the image that is stored in the phone. I want to store the location in mysql database table column.

Comment: Why would you store the location of the image from your phone? It is irrelevant for the web app.

Comment: Do you mean the geo-location or the path of the file on your phone?

Comment: If the GPS co-ordinates are in the EXIF information in the image that is uploaded, you should be able to extract them in your PHP code and store them in the database.

Comment: As you've tagged this with "geolocation" I assume you mean extracting geo data from the uploaded file, not trying to find the location the file was stored in the phone's filesystem, as some seem to have suggested. If so then droopsnoot's suggestion should be possible. Have you researched / tried anything so far in order try and solve it? I doubt you'd be the first person who wanted to do such a task.

Comment: I want to store the geolocation of the photo. Can anyone help with the code?